# Match email domain @xxxx.com of two columns from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables with client information but the names of the companies differ even if they are the same company as one of the tables was created manually involving errors.

So when trying to match it, the best way would be to match the domain of the email of the clients in both tables. Could you help me creating the SQL query for it?

Let's say Table 1 is:

```
company                 email
Nike                    john@nike.com
Yahoo                   carlos@yahoo.com
....(many others)       ....(many others)
```

and Table 2 is:

```
company                 email
Nike  Inc.              lucas@nike.com
Yahoo France            mike@yahoo.com
....(many others)       ....(many others)
```

I would kindly ask your help to build a query that would return the companies that match in both tables as they have the same domain in the email.

Like:

```
Companies_from_table_1     Companies_from_table_2     
Nike                       Nike Inc
Yahoo                      Yahoo france
Etc.                       Etc.
```

PS: it's for Oracle SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.company Companies_from_table_1, 
       t2.company Companies_from_table_2
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON REGEXP_SUBSTR(t1.email, '@.+') = REGEXP_SUBSTR(t2.email, '@.+')
```

`ORDER BY tX.company` by the table which stores canonical names recommended.

Comment: thank you, but it replies: Error: no such function: REGEXP_SUBSTR

Comment: @LuisM.deCarvajal https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303